# Migrate xamarin project from windows to mac os

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, migrate

I have migrated xamarin project from windows 10 to macos cataliina(10.15.5).

But I completely stuck on error when I am trying to run xamarin.ios project.
Hope for some advices.

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.10.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB3073: The command " if not exist
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/SuppClient/Portable/bin/Debug/x86"
>   md
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/SuppClient/Portable/bin/Debug/x86"
>   xcopy /s /y
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1/NativeBinaries/x86/."
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/SuppClient/Portable/bin/Debug/x86"
>   if not exist
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/SuppClient/Portable/bin/Debug/amd64"
>   md
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/SuppClient/Portable/bin/Debug/amd64"
>   xcopy /s /y
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8854.1/NativeBinaries/amd64/."
>   "/Users/dmitry/Desktop/APP/APP_code/1.9.8/SuppClient/Portable/bin/Debug/amd64""
>   exited with code 1. (MSB3073) (Application.Mobile.Client.Portable)

[image]

Comment: Open your project file and edit its post build event. Those commands used currently (like `xcopy`) are Windows only. You have to convert to UNIX/Linux specific commands such as `cp`. Well, if you do want quicker resolution for all platforms, write a PowerShell script that takes input, and then call it from post build event with proper parameters. PowerShell 6 and above is now cross platform, so you can rely on that portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Xamarin PCL .Net Framework to .Net Standard solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for yous sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.